# How to deploy react native app to apple store from windows machine

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, app-store, windows-11

I used windows machine to develop the react native app and deployed successfully on to google play store. Now I am trying to deploy the same app to apple App store from windows machine. Any lead will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: You will need to use macos, either locally or through a cloud service.

Comment: You need to have macOS environment and Xcode to compile a .ipa file.